# Preventing user navigation to activities after logout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have 3 activities:

1. LoginScreen.
2. MainScreen.
3. ProfileScreen.

The loginscreen is the main activity which gets called first time and at the clicking of login button I call the mainscreen activity by using following code:

```
finish(); // I am calling finish because I don't want user to press back key at mainscreen and get back to login screen.
Intent it = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MainScreen.class);
startActivity(it);
```

In my mainscreen I am having a logout button and I am using this code for loggin out:

```
finish();
Intent it = new Intent(MainScreen.this,LoginScreen.class);
containerObject.startActivity(it);
```

I don't know why but this code doesn't take me to login screen.

If I change the code from above to this code :

```
finish();
Intent it = new Intent(MainScreen.this,ProfileScreen.class);
containerObject.startActivity(it);
```

The code works absolutely fine and takes me to profilescreen.

Let me make it clear that I haved added all 3 activities to manifest.

Am I getting this problem just because "LoginScreen" is the main activity?

Comment: I would recommend a better way of handling transition to the login screen which will keep the activity stack in a conventional structure and avoid back button issues. Keep the main screen as the main (default) activity. Check here that the user is logged in, if not, invoke your login screen with `startActivityForResult`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities  When the user has logged in, have the login activity exit with `setResult()` which will return you to the main activity.

Comment: Besides mentioned in the first comment, why do you first call finish() and then send intent? Try to change order.

Comment: I appreciate your comments but it would be much appreciated if we can discuss what's going wrong with this code. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to change the order as I suggested?

Comment: I tried but nothing happed but I don't know what changes I made after but it got working. :)

Comment: That is reason to worry. If something worked out for unknown reason, there is no guarantee that same issue will not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

*Better late than never.*

In your logout button click handler you have to start the activity using 
containerObject, as you have already finished the MainScreen activity, so 
you have to go to the parent container of your activity.

```
logoutButtonClick(../..[

    finish();
    Intent it = new Intent(MainScreen.this,LoginScreen.class);
    containerObject.startActivity(it);
}
```

To ensure the activity is finished call this.finish within the on click handler, but after starting your intent.

```
logoutButtonClick(../.. {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class));
    this.finish();
}
```

Then override your onBackPressed event when in the LoginScreen activity. So 
the backpress will keep taking the user to the login screen.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class));
    this.finish();
}
```

I'm not sure if how you are wanting to manage your navigation for the duration of the 
app between the three activities so I won't go into more detail to navigate between the 
ProfileScreen activity and the other two, but I'm sure you have enough information to move 
forward with this.

When I'm wanting to secure a password protected area of my app, I override and manage 
all my backpress events and carefully manage the navigation throughout the app and the application lifecycle, so an app cannot be closed and reopened on an activity that is secured with a password.